# How to search in row and add those row values in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

|  | Percentage |
| --- | --- |
| NaN | 1.576020 |
| Redmond | 4.264524 |
| England | 4.975278 |
| England - Street XY | 5.346106 |
| Denmark Street x | 7.601978 |
| England – Street wy | 11.773795 |
| England – Street AU | 13.936959 |
| Redmond street COX | 50.525340 |
| Baharin | 0 |

I need to create another data frame which sums all rows starting with Redmond Percentage, all all rows starting with England   followed by street namePercentage, all rows starting with England only Percentage and all all rows starting with Redmond.

How to do it using python.

In above case output should be

|  | Percentage |
| --- | --- |
| NaN | 1.576020 |
| Redmond | 50.525340 |
| England | 4.975278 |
| England with street | 11.773795 |
| Denmark | 7.60 |
| Baharin | 0 |

Comment: @MustafaAydın Thanks. Finally somebody got the markdown right. I thought I got it, but the preview is misleading.

Comment: the output df is not summing the rows in input df. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this:

```
df = df.reset_index()
m = df['index'].astype(str).str.contains('Street')
street_df = df.loc[m]
street_df = street_df.groupby(street_df['index'].str.split(' ').str[0]).agg({'Percentage': sum}).reset_index()
street_df['index'] = street_df['index'] + ' with street'
result = pd.concat([df[~m],street_df])
```